# How to I regroup columns in R

Tags: r

Hi I have a data set as such. I would like to rearrange the column where the same countries will be together. Thanks.

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(New_Argentina = c(2, 4, 6), New_China = c(5, 6, 
 8), New_Belarus = c(8, 8, 10), Old_Argentina = c(11, 10, 12), 
Old_China = c(14, 12, 14), Old_Belarus = c(17, 14, 16)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


  df1>
  New_Argentina New_China New_Belarus Old_Argentina Old_China Old_Belarus
      <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
        2         5           8            11        14          17
        4         6           8            10        12          14
        6         8          10            12        14          16
```

How to I rearrange the columns to this

Result>

```
  New_Argentina Old_Argentina New_China Old_China New_Belarus Old_Belarus
        <dbl>         <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
         2            11         5        14           8          17
         4            10         6        12           8          14
         6            12         8        14          10          16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this

```
df1[order(gsub(".*_","",colnames(df1)))]

  New_Argentina Old_Argentina New_Belarus Old_Belarus New_China Old_China
1             2            11           8          17         5        14
2             4            10           8          14         6        12
3             6            12          10          16         8        14
```